# regex lookbehind with a date

Tags: regex

I fail to solve following problem:

I need to extract the 7 digit number (e.g. `2774800`) in the middle of a string with regex. This is from an invoice. In each invoice I have a different 7-digit number. The product description also always changes, only the date always stays like dd.mm.yyyy, so I would use this as indicator and do a lookbehind search for the 7-digit number, but I can't get that to work.

> Product description that always changes (sometimes here is a bracket) **2774800** 21.11.2014

What I used to indicate the date is:

```
((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).[12]\d{3})
```

For the 7 digit:

```
(?=\d{7}\s)\d+
```

I can't get them to work together correctly, so that the indicator is the date and it matches the 7-digit number.

Comment: couldn't find anything specific to my question, but alright i guess ill dive into books again.

Comment: Try `\b\d{7}(?=\s+(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.[12]\d{3})`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0Y6yp/1).

Comment: im using it in rpa to extract from a pdf invoice and import it into a structured db, which i then export to excel... with uipath

also thx for ur help, it seems to work so far, ill do some testing and come back much appreciated

Comment: I realized that there's also numbers with 6 or 8 digits, so i Just added 6,7,8 in the bracket like this, just incase someone else would need it:
> \b\d{6,8}(?=\s+(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.[12]\d{3})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
\b\d{7}(?=\s+(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.[12]\d{3})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0Y6yp/1).

Or, to match 6 to 8 digit numbers:

```
\b\d{6,8}(?=\s+(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.[12]\d{3})
```

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d{7}` - seven digits
- `(?=\s+(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.[12]\d{3})` - a positive lookahead that requires 1+ whitespaces and then a date-like pattern immediately to the right of the current location.